# Kubeflow: Notebook server stuck on loading

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, mlops

Whenever I try to create a Kubeflow notebook server to build a pipeline from a jupyter notebook, it keeps loading forever without displaying any error.

I'm currently using a Kubeflow dashboard that's already up and running on a server, so I didn't deploy it myself and I'm not working on a local instance to use the terminal.

Any idea what the origin of the problem might be and how to solve it?

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgQyS.png) that might explain better.

Comment: You can check the error message hovering over the loading circle using your mouse